# How to number References section using \bibliography{...} command?

Tags: bibtex, sectioning, bibliographies, numbering

I use the`\bibliography{bibtexfile}{}` command to generate my bibliography, but this creates a References section with the numbering suppressed. How do I make the number for the section appear?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  It will be much easier for people to help you if you provide a *minimum working example* (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  A MWE means that people trying to answer your question can just copy and paste your code and then see if they can fix it.  With your question as is, they need to develop a whole document around the one line of code you've provided.  A MWE helps us help you; taking the time to create one will ease the way to an answer.

Comment: In particular, do indicate which document class you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number reference headline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412441/number-reference-headline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tocbibind` package and the `numbib` option this will work for the standard classes such as `article` and `book`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{filecontents}{mybiblo.bib}
  @article{MBBL2014,
    author = {Ministeriet for by Bolig og Landdistrikter},
    title = {{Matriklens Udvidelse}},
    url = {http://grunddata-ejendom-adresse.dk/matriklens\_udvidelse},
    urldate = {2015-04-20},
    year = {2014} 
  }
\end{filecontents}






\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\cite{MBBL2014}


\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybiblo}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412542/37907 I hate when this happens.

Comment: @Johannes_B: What do you mean?

Comment: Same Q, same A, double effort.

Comment: @Johannes_B: The other one was closed anyway