# Number reference headline

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I try to number the header of my references. I succeeded to add the number to the table of contents, but I can't get it to work for the header.

To add the number to the toc I used:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section} \protect\numberline{\thesection}References}
```

If I try the same for `\refname`, I get 5References without space.

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\protect\numberline{\thesection References}}
```

When I put the references title outside the curly brackets, it's shown in a new line. What am I missing here? The full bibliography call looks like this:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\protect\numberline{\thesection References}}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}References}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bachelor}
```

EDIT 1: 
As @TeXnician stated, a tilde would solve the problem. It is not very elegant, though, as I have to use approximatly three of them to get the same space as in the other headlines.

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\protect\numberline{\thesection~~~References}}
```

EDIT 2:
@Werner suggested a shorter solution, but it throws multiple errors, when I try to integrate it into my .tex file. Here's a short reproducable example which replicates the errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@Article{draxler2010sample,
    author    = {Draxler, Clemens},
    title     = {Sample size determination for Rasch model tests},
    journal   = {Psychometrika},
    year      = {2010},
    volume    = {75},
    number    = {4},
    pages     = {708--724},
    publisher = {Springer},
}

\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\section{First Chapter}

\citep{draxler2010sample}

\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\oldsection{#2}}% Update \section to gobble *
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\appendix

\section{R Code}

\subsection{Greedings Function}

\begin{lstlisting}
    print("Hello World")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\thesection~References`?

Comment: or `{\thesection\ References}`

Comment: The tilde works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: The other question might be better suited as a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tocbibind`.

[image: jeypeuNumbib]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}% <---------

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{draxler2010sample,
    author    = {Draxler, Clemens},
    title     = {Sample size determination for Rasch model tests},
    journal   = {Psychometrika},
    year      = {2010},
    volume    = {75},
    number    = {4},
    pages     = {708--724},
    publisher = {Springer},
}

\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\section{First Chapter}

\citep{draxler2010sample}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\appendix

\section{R Code}

\subsection{Greedings Function}

\begin{lstlisting}
    print("Hello World")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the references section of an article is set using `\section*{\refname}`. You can override this to print a full `\section` (not starred) by using the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\oldsection{#2}}% Update \section to gobble *

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The update to `\section` takes two arguments, the first of which is known to be the `*` in `\section*`. It merely gobbles this without doing anything and then calls the traditional `\section` with the second argument. This forces a numbered sectional unit.

Since the references section is now numbered, it'll make its way into the ToC by default.

Comment: As it seemed to be a more elegant way to solve the problem I tried it. It adds the numbered header and is shown in the toc, but it throws errors like `Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete`, `Too many }'s` and `Overfull \hbox`. In addition it messes with my `\appendix` as all sections in the appendix are now interpreted as subsections of the reference section. Maybe it's caused by using `\bibliography{...}` instead of `\begin{thebibiography}{x} ...`?

Comment: @jeypeu: Can you provide a complete, minimal document that replicates your current problematic behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, contain only the necessary (minimal) content to replicate the issue and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile with duplication.

Comment: See the updated question.