# Including reference list as numbered section in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing

When I include my reference list in the table of contents, it is included as an unnumbered section unlike all the other sections. Is there a way to change this?

I'm using the following programming:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

% Table of content               
\usepackage{etoolbox} % http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

%References.bib
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{cite1,
author={Name LastName},
title={Title},
year={2018}}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter 
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\begingroup%
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}% <cmd>
{\vspace*{50\p@}}% <search>
{}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\oldtableofcontents%
\endgroup%
 }
\makeatother

% Reference list
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Theory etc.}
\cite{cite1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I really hope somebody can help me.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I used the freedom to make your code a complete minimal working example with bibliography... But please make clear (and edit if you wish) if you are using chapters, and if the references should be a numbered chapter or a numbered section.

Comment: Hi Bijarke, this should be able to help [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246933/how-to-number-references-section-using-bibliography-command).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the lines
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
This can be achieved only with biblatex, use the options `heading=subbibnumbered, title={References}` for the command `\printbibliography`. If you do not want the bibliography to be numbered use `subbibintoc` instead of `subbibnumbered`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

% Table of content               
\usepackage{etoolbox} % http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

%References.bib
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{cite1,
author={Name LastName},
title={Title},
year={2018}}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter 
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\begingroup%
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}% <cmd>
{\vspace*{50\p@}}% <search>
{}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\oldtableofcontents%
\endgroup%
 }
\makeatother

% Reference list
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Theory etc.}
\cite{cite1}

%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, title={References}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Render of MWE:
[image: Render of MWE]

Comment: Hi,
This worked perfectly, thank you so much! It even solved my issue with the top margin on the reference list page being very wide.

Thanks again.

Cheers