# Appearing of a Reference header in my reference

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning

I created a file with a list of references and managed to cite it right, my problem is in this extra "References" word that appear before my references  (circled red)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{An article with citations}
\author{myself}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{introduction}

This article is about citations. I read a good book~\cite{hassan2012}. I read a good article~\cite{hassan2013}. I like to use \LaTeX`\cite{latex}.

\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references}
%\bibliography{../mendeley} will vary depending on OS u r using
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to https://tex.stackexchange.com/. Try this `\renewcommand{\bibname}{}` in your preamble. or remove `\section{References}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue

```
\bibliography{references}
```

the `\jobname.bbl` file is loaded, which usually starts with

```
\begin{thebibliography}{...}
```

`article.cls` defines the `thebibliography` environment to start with

```
\section*{\refname}
```

The solution is easy: just remove `\section{References}` from your code. If you want the *References* section to be numbered, then please give a look at [How to number References section using `\bibliography{…}` command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246933/82917)

Comment: Great thanks a lot 
I added this line
\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}
and also removed \section{References}